# jmeter, why always getting status warning

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter, stress-testing

im trying to run jmeter test with these values:

[image]

and in view results table always get records with status "warning"

[image]

maybe someone can explain what i do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener, it won't fix anything but you will get at least response code/message

Your test plan doesn't seem valid to me, you know, when it comes to performance testing of web applications [well-behaved JMeter test must represent a real user using a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) with 100% accuracy

So I would recommend *at least** adding a [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) and configure it to send [User-Agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) header representing the browser you want to simulate:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same issue. If you are behind the firewall of your organisation, then you need to go to the advanced tab of Http request step and  fill up your company specific scheme, host, port, username and password. It will start working. Hope this helps